# `touch` a file that uses ACL on Linux causes "Operation not permitted"

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

In Java code I want to "touch" a file. I want to update the timestamps to the current time. The file uses ACL. And this seems to be the problem.

The file:

```
$ ll file.xml 
-rw-rwxrw-+ 1 root root 8611 Oct  4 17:28 file.xml
$ getfacl file.xml 
# file: file.xml
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:tomcat8:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::rw-
```

And my Java app runs from Tomcat 8 with user tomcat8. A `sudo -u tomcat8 touch file.xml` works. It also works if I completely remove ACL and set tomcat8 as owner. But this is not possible in the production environment.

So at first I tried Apache common-io:

```
FileUtils.touch(path);
```

This causes an IOException. I debugged it a bit more and found out that the library calls `FileSystem.setLastModifiedTime` which calls the Linux function `utimes`.

I debugged the Linux `touch` command and saw it calls another more modern function: `utimensat(0, NULL, NULL, 0)`. It also calls `dup2`and duplicates the file descriptor.

So I built my own touch method in Java:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
FileTime fileTimeNow = FileTime.fromMillis(time);
BasicFileAttributeView fileAttributeView = Files.getFileAttributeView(derivative.toPath(), BasicFileAttributeView.class);
fileAttributeView.setTimes(fileTimeNow, fileTimeNow, fileTimeNow);
```

This throws an Exception too (Operation not permitted).

Internally it calls `utimensat(69, NULL, [{1538666780, 483000000}, {1538666780, 483000000}], 0)`.

I can not set `null` on `.setTimes(...)`. This call gets ignored. And there is no Java-way to duplicate a file descriptor (dup2). So I can not test further steps to make it more like Linux' touch.

How to make this working when a file uses ACL? I don't want to run external programs (touch).

Comment: External call to `touch` will not help you either as that call will be performed under same `tomcat8` user. I'd better ask Linux admins to change permissions for that file or move it somewhere where `tomcat8` user has permissions

Comment: @Ivan, I added this to my question: "A `sudo -u tomcat8 touch file.xml` works. It also works if I completely remove ACL and set tomcat8 as owner. But this is not possible in the production environment."

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not written concurrently, you can open it, read its first byte, and write it back again at offset zero.  This will update the modification time of the file without requiring ownership permissions.

(By the way, the ACL looks really curious, particularly the `other:: rw-` part.)

Comment: This may work but it causes more IO and on a failure it may cause damaged files. And it's more like a workaround than a real solution.
Maybe the ACL is because I did `chmod +w ...`. (for testing) But it still didn't work if the ACL is set.

Comment: The mtime update will happen even if you write the *same* byte, so your storage must be really broken if that can corrupt the file (in the absence of concurrent writes to the same offset, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Here's `man utimensat`:

> Permissions requirements
>
> To set both file timestamps to the current time (i.e., times is NULL, or both tv_nsec fields specify UTIME_NOW), either:
>
> 1. the caller must have write access to the file;
> 2. the caller's effective user ID must match the owner of the file; or
> 3. the caller must have appropriate privileges.
>
> **To make any change other than setting both timestamps to the current time (i.e., times is not NULL**, and neither tv_nsec field is UTIME_NOW and neither tv_nsec field is UTIME_OMIT), **either condition 2 or 3  above  must
>          apply.**

You have #1, but not #2 or #3. If you ask `touch` to explicitly set the time to the current timestamp, it fails as well:

```
$ getfacl test | sed -e "s/$USER/myuser/"
# file: test
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:myuser:rwx
group::r--
mask::rwx
other::r--

$ touch -d "@$(date +%s)" test
touch: setting times of ‘test’: Operation not permitted
```

I don't have any good suggestions for what to do instead though. You could either make a no-op change to the file, or call `touch` as an external command:

```
String path="some path";
// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52651585 for why we're not doing this via Java
int result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "touch", "--", path }).waitFor();
if(result != 0) throw new IOException("Can't update timestamp");
```

Comment: Interesting find. This matches my find that touch sets NULL, which seems to be impossible through Java. I think about trying JNA. But it feels like a big overhead for a simple touch.